# what if hiring process takes long time after almost all interviews?

Tags: hiring-process

It's over two months that I'm in recruitment process by a company which usually has many opportunities in the field of software development every month, I done almost all interviews (2 HR + 1 Acc Manager + 1 Technical), but every time when I follow up my application they show their interest to hire me soon but they also postpone me to further vacancy in near future for different reasons(i.e. there is another candidate which took longer time in process, etc) each time, I'm interested in there but am really not sure for the result.

what's your opinion about this? How many chance you think I have? 
Should I wait or forget them and look for other opportunities in other companies?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

**Edit:** one question is [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p) but that question is about Follow-up, as you see my problem and question is not about follow-up, and the situations as not the same.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate, but I can't seem to find a good one. Personally, after 2 weeks I consider it a lost cause. Taking that long to get through the hiring process does not bode well for the other bureaucracy at the company.

Comment: @Telastyn I searched for questions but didn't find completely matched result that's why I posted new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame, my question is completely different from that, the question is about follow-up but this one is not about following up and there is a different situation here.

Comment: What should you do is off topic... the only way to fix this is to ask about following up... so yeah its a dupe

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame, you think this is duplicate, but I and maybe some others don't think. however I'm not sure other moderators will think as same as you or not. I think I should wait for more interesting answers and all answers here is different from answers of question mentioned by you

Comment: Asking what you should (As you have done here) is off topic. So if you can change your question to not ask what to do and not ask about following up, and not poll for user opinions, then I will retract my vote.  As it stands if it is not a duplicate it is off topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be common or it may not.  Depends to much on the company.  For what chance you have, your guess is probably going to be better than mine.

For your third question, You should not wait on Company A but you should not forget them either.  Keep looking for a new job until you have a signed offer in hand.

When I am looking for employment the only time I stop is when I have a signed offer.  Until then I am not going to stop looking just because I have been through a lot of interviews with one company.  It would be slightly annoying if I accepted a different position after taking time off work to attend interviews but it is just part of the process.

If you really want to work for Company A and you get an offer from Company B, let Company A know about the offer from Company B.  This puts a clock on Company A (you would be amazed at how fast the hiring process can go if there is a clock and they want to bring you on).  You may get an offer on the spot from Company A or they may tell you to take the offer from Company B because the position was offered to another candidate and you are their second choice.  This is what happened to me at my current position (I had to take the first offer but oh well, all turned out good in the end).

Answer (score 3):

The larger the company, the slower its inner workings. The person who want to hire you would like to do so right away, but they likely have to wait until:

- They interviewed all other 94 candidates who also have interviews scheduled
- They found time to write a detailed report about every interview for the hiring board
- The hiring board found a date to have a meeting where they discuss all the reports and decide which candidate to hire
- The hiring board has written a protocol about the meeting and sent their proposal to some other boards, directors, anti-discrimination representatives etc. which have a say in who to hire.
- Those other people have found time to read that protocol and gave their OK. Did I mention that most of these people have also other responsibilities with much higher priority? Also, two of them are chronically ill and one disappeared without a trace.
- A background check was performed on all candidates.
- The human resource department finished writing the work contracts (who are desperately overworked and still haven't finished writing the contracts from the last three hiring waves)
- The legal department has reviewed all the work contracts (yes, they are standard contracts, so this is quite pointless, but the big boss gave order to do this after that ugly lawsuit in 2003)
- Those contracts were mailed out

That's just how big corporations work. When you want a job fast, try applying to a smaller company.

Comment: as that company is a large one(with over 1500 employees) then exactly the reasons you mentioned is probable reasons of postpone and taking long time, as exactly one of these reasons were mentioned by them when I followed up, and also the last statement in your answer _When you want a job fast, try applying to a smaller company._ is really interesting (for who don't want a to work for big and too much organized companies)

Comment: You forgot to mention that once the perfect candidate was approved then accounting decided to cut the budget for the potential hire so the contract sent out has a figure 30% lower than previously agreed. ( which will most likely cause the contract not to be signed and the entire process will start again )

Answer (score 3):

If they've already given you the offer in writing, and you've signed it, then you should wait until the offer takes effect.

If there is no written offer, there is no offer period. There is nothing to wait for, and you should certainly move on to other interviews.